# add SoapHeader after SetClass in SoapServer in PHP

Tags: php, soap, soapheader, soapserver

i have a class that set in $obj->setClass() to handle requests in SoapServer .
but now i need to set some soapHeader inside that class.
How i can set SoapHeader inside that class or access the SoapServer Object ?

### server.php

```
$svr = new SoapServer('http://localhost?wsdl');
$svr->setClass("SampleClass");
$svr->handle();
```

### SampleClass

```
class sample { 
 public function test() { 
   // add some soapHeader to $svr object
 }
}
```

--Edit--
found the solution :)

just make $svr global inside the handler class functions and using addSoapHeader .
if you use addSoapHeader in svr object , it will be overwriten with ->handle() .

```
class sample { 
 public function test() {  
global $svr;
$svr->addSoapHedaer($soapHeader); 
   // add some soapHeader to $svr object
 }
}
```

you need to make $soapHeader before with SoapHeader PHP native class